# Change sound volume in Chromium

Tags: c++, chromium

How do i change sound volume with chromium api? Be it html5 audio or a flash youtube video, is there a uniform way to change the volume? I need to change the volume for the whole browser, additionally to volume setting the user can access on the page. Something like the win7 sound mixer, where it changes volume for the entire process.
I have tried to use different chromium classes, such as `HtmlMediaElement`, but with no effect.
I only need this on windows, so is there a way to do something with winapi, instead of chromium api? 
Please help